# Maven + Zuul + Spring-boot cannot access FilerConstants class

Tags: maven, spring-boot, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I am trying to write a custom [route filter](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-netflix/2.0.0.M7/single/spring-cloud-netflix.html#_how_to_write_a_route_filter) with zuul. But this import is failing :

`import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.support.FilterConstants;`

[image: spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar]

I've been trying to change the version in my pom.xml file but it always end up breaking springboot configuration. Currently my pom looks like [this spring-boot guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/routing-and-filtering/).

I am quite confused between spring-cloud-netflix, com.netflix and how they work togetheir.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>search-api-layer</groupId>
    <artifactId>search-api-layer</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>application.GateWayApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Zuul -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zuul</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jolt -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bazaarvoice.jolt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jolt-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bazaarvoice.jolt</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-utils</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- spring test -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Brixton.SR5</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml so that I can reproduce the issue?

Comment: i just did :). Ihave tried several version for both spring-cloud-starter zuul and spring-cloud-netflix-core.